# read a csv file with comma as delimiter and escaping quotes in psql

Tags: sql, csv, greenplum

I want to read a csv file which is separated by comma (`,`) but want to ignore comma within the double quotes (`""`). I want to store the result into a table.

Example:

```
abc,00.000.00.00,00:00:00:00:00:00,Sun Nov 01 00:00:00 EST 0000,Sun Nov 01 00:00:00 EST 0000,"Apple, Inc.",abcd-0000abc-a,abcd-abcd-a0000-00
```

Here I don't want to split on Apple, .

I know there exists csv reader in python and I can use it in plpython but that's slow considering millions of such strings! I would like a pure psql method!

Comment: Apple and psql? Where and what are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of reading a CSV file with an External Table using the CSV format.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ext_expenses ( name text, 
date date,  amount float4, category text, desc1 text ) 
LOCATION ('gpfdist://etlhost-1:8081/*.txt', 
          'gpfdist://etlhost-2:8082/*.txt')
FORMAT 'CSV' ( DELIMITER ',' )
LOG ERRORS SEGMENT REJECT LIMIT 5;
```

This was taken from the Greenplum docs too.

http://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/530/admin_guide/external/g-example-4-single-gpfdist-instance-with-error-logging.html